# Vector of column names

Tags: r

I have a data set. Data1

```
    Type    x1        x2      x3  ...
1:  type1   1.54    1.48    1.88    
2:  type2   1.46    1.99    1.48
3:  type1   2.01    1.02    1.03
...
```

I want to create a vector, x, of the column names excluding the first column.
It is surely simple, I am a novice.

Comment: Try ```names(Data1)[-1]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by user Matthew Farant, the function `names()` gives you the column names of a `data.frame`, e.g. `names(Data1)`.

To get the names excluding the first column, you can either subset the vector of names, e.g. `names(Data1)[-1]`, or you can subset the data, and get the names of the subset of data excluding the first column, `names(Data1[,-1]`.

In case your data is a `matrix`, you can use the `colnames()` function instead.